# How to caculate the summation of successive modular inverses?

Tags: prime-numbers, number-theory

$p$ is a big prime. $p>2^{2048}$.
So how to caculate the summation of successive modular inverses over $p$?
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p+1}{2}-1}{i^{-1}}\pmod p
$$
As to $p$ is a big prime, it's impossible to caculate the modular inverses one by one and sum them at last.
I found someone give a formula which approximates the result, but I couldn't prove it.
$$
p - \frac{2^{p}\pmod {p^2}-1}{p} \pmod p
$$
Can you help me prove the formula, or give your answers to calculate the summation? Thanks sincerely!

Comment: Could you give us a hint where this is used in Cryptography? And the link of the someone?

Comment: @kelalaka Someone give the formula [here](https://t.zsxq.com/ZJe6yFI) in their code about the problem "more calc". I don't know where this is used, I just meet the problem in a CTF, then I used google search, but found nothing related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum you are inquiring about is pretty much the right side of the [Fermat quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_quotient) identity discovered by Eisenstein (proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2017110)):
$$
-2q_p(2) = \sum_{i=1}^{(p-1)/2} 1/i \pmod{p}\,,
$$
where $q_p(a) = \frac{a^{p-1} - 1}{p}$.

Thus the sum can be computed as $-2 \frac{2^{p-1} - 1}{p} \bmod p$. Because computing $2^{p-1}$ is not feasible for very large $p$, and because one only requires the result divided by $p$ and then reduced again by $p$, computing $\frac{2^{p-1} - 1}{p}$ can be performed as $\frac{(2^{p-1} \bmod p^2) - 1}{p}$ without any precision loss. And to absorb that factor of $2$, one can compute instead $-\frac{(2^{p} \bmod p^2) - 1}{p} \bmod p$, which is exactly the formula you found.